# how to disable the button clicked style css

Tags: css

how can i disable the clicked button style { the black border}

```css
.cols-1 button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0px -160px -40px 0px;
    background-color: #aec7ca;
    color: #ebebeb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    padding: 25px 85px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: There is no black border?

Comment: no there is a black border and i need to disable it

Comment: As tkahn mentioned below, this is an important browser feature and you shouldn't disable it. For users like me who have trouble using a mouse, we rely on that black outline to let us know which element is actively focused (by pressing "tab" and moving between buttons/links on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the style that the button gets when it's in focus (using tabs or by clicking), it's removed using:

```css
outline: none;
```

However this is considered bad for accessibility so consider keeping the outline, but giving it a more subtle styling.

```css
.myButton:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline-color: #cccccc;
}
```